# How to Loop & rename MySQL table in Perl

Tags: mysql, perl, loops, dbi

Could you plesae teach me how to Loop & rename MySQL table in Perl. Thanks.

my code snippet attached

```
use strict; 
use warnings; 
use DBI; 

my $dbh = DBI->connect( 
    'DBI:mysql:database=dbdev;host=localhost', 
    'dbdev', 
    'dbdevpw', 
    { RaiseError => 1, AutoCommit => 1 }, 
); 

my $sql = RENAME TABLE old_table TO new_table; 
my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql); 

while (<DATA>){ 
    chomp; 
    // How to implement the Rename all the old tables with the while loop.


    $sth->execute(); 
}
```

Comment: What's the downvote for this question for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code can be used to rename all tables in the database:

```
my @tables = map @$_, @{ $dbh->selectall_arrayref('SHOW TABLES') };

for my $table (@tables) {
    $dbh->do("RENAME TABLE $table TO new_${table}");
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming your list of tables live in **DATA**.

```
while (<DATA>){ 
    chomp; 
     $dbh->do("RENAME TABLE ? TO ?", undef, $_, "new_" . $_);
}
```

You might also want to take a look at `perldoc DBI`